# Django No module named context_processors

Tags: python, django

I'm migrating a django app to a new server and I've installed all the dependencies. When I did a restart I got this error which looks weird. I'm using django 1.7 on the server. I have never experienced a similar issue and I'm guessing likely it's a conflict with another python app with the name context.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://stage.kenyabuzz.com/

Django Version: 1.7.10
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.redirects',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'autocomplete_light',
 'djangorestframework',
 'haystack',
 'lamusoftware.generic',
 'mptt',
 'bootstrapform',
 'sorl.thumbnail',
 'oauth2client',
 'articles',
 'banners',
 'common',
 'directory',
 'events',
 'galleries',
 'marketplace',
 'movies',
 'pages',
 'profiles',
 'search',
 'stats',
 'minidetector',
 'mobile',
 'reports',
 'favorites',
 'braces',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'wordofmouth',
 'ckeditor',
 'django_mobile',
 'markup_deprecated',
 'whoosh',
 'rest')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
 'minidetector.Middleware',
 'mobileesp.middleware.MobileDetectionMiddleware',
 'kb.middleware.log_ip_middleware.SetRemoteAddrFromForwardedFor',
 'kb.middleware.log_ip_middleware.RedirectMovie')


Traceback:
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  105.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/minidetector/__init__.py" in detected
  47.         return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb/pages/views.py" in home
  140.     context = RequestContext(request)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/template/context.py" in __init__
  208.         for processor in get_standard_processors() + processors:
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/template/context.py" in get_standard_processors
  186.             func = import_string(path)
File "/home/kbuzz/webapps/kenyabuzz/lib/python2.7/Django-1.7.10-py2.7.egg/django/utils/module_loading.py" in import_string
  26.     module = import_module(module_path)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named context_processors
```

Comment: Do you have the `context_processors` set in your `settings.py` file? And how are you importing the `ReqestContext` in your view?

Comment: Seems like it's breaking update in allauth:

http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog.html#from-0-21-0

Comment: yeah it was actually the version's one was the most latest